# Does the person that declined you on Facebook get a notification on Facebook after one year that the person that they declined can now add them again?

Tags: facebook, facebook-friend-request

So someone I know I sent a friend request like a year ago and she declined it and it has been a year since that has happened and I still can’t send her a friend request but on one of my other accounts I still can add her on that account.  Does this mean that they get notified that it’s been a year since they have declined you and they can now send you another friend request and they set it to where I still can’t add them?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the person's profile and the button says "Pending" then that means they didn't see the request or ignored it.  If you have the option to add them again then that means the request was rejected.  If the person you sent the request to marked the request as spam then you will not be able to send them another request again.